# ngx-cookie gets deleted when link is opened in new tab in Angular Application

Tags: javascript, angular, session, cookies, ngx-cookie-service

I have used a PC to serve the website via LAN connection and use the IPv4 address instead of localhost for hosting the website on LAN.

I'm using the npm package `http-server` for serving the `dist` compiled angular application.

I'm using `ngx-cookie-service` for manipulating cookies in the angular application.
However, the cookies get deleted when I open a page via `router.navigate()`. Also, the cookies don't always get deleted as well.

So I'm kinda confused as to what is happening with the cookies.
What can be the reason?

P.S. I have not implemented session in the backend though.

Angular version : 10+
ngx-cookie-service: 11.0.2
browser: chrome 86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
There are many people facing the same problem as you are: https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service/issues/86

Some people suggested to fill out all the parameters of the SET method:

```
this.cookieService.set(
 cookieName,
 cookieValue,
 expirationDate,
 '/',
 someData,
 true, // secure flag
 'None' // sameSite property
);
```

Comment: Let me clarify, I'm using ngx-cookie-service but the cookies get auto-deleted when I'm using on xampp but not on any shared hosting. Why is  this so?

Comment: What's the version of your ngx-cookie-service ?

There are many people facing the same problem as you are:
https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service/issues/86

Some suggested to fill all the parameterers of the SET method:

this._cookieService.set(
cookieName,
cookieValue,
expirationDate,
'/',
someData,
true, <- secure flag
'None' <- sameSite property
);

Have you tried this ?

Comment: I'm using ``` "ngx-cookie-service": "^11.0.2"```. But I think the problem was the ```path``` where the cookie was set. I defined the path as you mentioned & it worked.

Does lazy loading effect the cookie creation?

Comment: Great! I'm gonna edit my answer then.
Lazy loading routes should be able to access the cookies normally since cookies belong to the domain.